# Is there any research on the influence of college professors' political views on graduates?

Tags: education, political-spectrum

Much hay has been made regarding education gap in partisan affiliation (or ideological differences, make your pick) in USA.

One thing that I rarely seen mentioned is any ***information*** of **whether (or how much) this gap is affected by political leanings/views of college professors**.

Of course, it's easy to find *discussions* on the topic (predictably, people on the right end of the political spectrum blaming "liberal college professors" - *for full disclosure, i'm fully convinced they are correct in said blame, my more-naive reasoning based on a [natural experiment conducted when a lot of highly-educated former-USSR immigrants settled in USA post 1980](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14983/do-non-educated-people-tend-more-to-the-right-conservative-political-wing/14990#14990)*).

## ***But what I'm after is actual data/research on the topic.***

It's easy to think up invalid research (compare students from less liberal colleges to those in more liberal ones). But that is deeply flawed on many levels, the simplest of which is that the student pool will be unevenly selected, both due to demographics-driven selection *and* self-selection based on college's reputation.

What I'm looking for is research that is reasonably well constructed, that tries to adjust for things like student populations' initial leanings; their majors, and other possible confounding  factors.